# value. in column names and unwanted column created in Shiny but not in R

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I am working with multiple csv files, and I want to perform some operations on each of the files, and then merge the resultant dataframes into one dataframe and download the output as csv file using Shiny. I decided to reference my script within Shiny using 'source', because the app runs much faster that way instead of putting the code within server.R of shiny. When I run the code without shiny, I got my [desired dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsejRDOWtfVDVoM28/view?usp=sharing), but when I run it with Shiny, the columns of the [data frame has `value.` added to the column names](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsV3NLLUhrd05keXc/view?usp=sharing). In addition, additional column named "visible" is created. I have tried to add `check.names in`read,csv() but it does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

These are my [dummy excel files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0MjygvBH6bsalg4N19KM0tIeGc/view?usp=sharing). And this is shiny code:

```
 library(shiny)
 ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidPage(
     titlePanel("FOO FILES"),
     sidebarLayout(
       sidebarPanel(
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
       ),
       mainPanel(
         tableOutput('contents')
       )
     )
   )
  )


 library(shiny)
 library(dplyr)
 options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100*1024^2)
 server <-  function(input, output) {
   getData <- reactive({

    withProgress(message = 'progress', value = 0, {
  # Number of times we'll go through the loop
  n <- 100
       for (i in 1:n) {
         # Increment the progress bar, and update the detail text.
         incProgress(1/n)    
    # Pause for 0.1 seconds to simulate a long computation.
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
       }
     })
    source('foo.R') 
    })
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { 
     paste("katabiz-", 
        format(Sys.time(), "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S"), ".csv", sep="")  
    },
    content = function(file) { 
      write.csv(getData(), file, row.names=FALSE)    
    })
  }
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The R script (`foo.R`) that I referenced within Shiny using 'source' is this:

```
 file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
 df.list <- lapply(file.list, read.csv, header = TRUE, quote = "", fill = 
 FALSE)
 numfiles = length(df.list)
 kata_csv1 = list()
 for (i in 1:numfiles)
 {
   kata_csv = function(y){
     JSON_csv = as.data.frame(df.list[i])
     lastrow = nrow(JSON_csv)
     shift = function(x, n){
       c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
     }
     JSON_csv$companyID1 = shift(JSON_csv$companyID1, 1)
     JSON_csv = JSON_csv[-lastrow, ]
     JSON_csv 
   }
   kata_csv1[[i]] = kata_csv(df.list[i])
 }
 newTable = do.call(rbind, kata_csv1)
 colnames(newTable) <- c("companyID1",  "name", "NZBN", 
                    "ultimateHoldingCompany",   "uhcCountry",   
 "companyStatus")
 newTable
```

Comment: Why don't you create a function for the code that is in foo.R , source the file at the top and call your function instead?

Comment: what will be the arguments in the function? I am to load CSV files from a folder. Can you give an example to demonstrate your contribution? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like you are not using any shiny values in your source file, so you do not need to pass any arguments, you just need to return the final dataframe, that you created.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks.